# Problems creating in the CustomUser model to authenticate with email and password DJANGO

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am making my first rest_framework platform with django and JWT, the problem that arises is that it is using the username as a password and I want to change it to email which is the generic that always works, I have followed tutorials but I do not know if it is how the project is structured, but I can not make the platform not to throw me error when I run python manage.py runserver.

The project is structured where I separate all the models in different files inside a folder called Models.

```
api
 -models
   -CustomUser.py
 -serializers
 -views
 -__init__.py
 -models.py
```

I have followed the tutorials to create the following:

**api.models.CustomUser**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','password']
```

**base.setting.py**

```
I tried with:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "api.CustomUser"
```

**ERROR Message**

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.10\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.10\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 546, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
api.LogContracts.user: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "api.models.CustomUser"

ERROR MESSAGE:
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\utils.py", line 15, in make_model_tuple
    app_label, model_name = model.split(".")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.10\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.10\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.10\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class LogEntry(models.Model):
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 192, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 369, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 865, in contribute_to_class
    super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, private_only=private_only, **kwargs)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 375, in contribute_to_class
    lazy_related_operation(
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 86, in lazy_related_operation
    return apps.lazy_model_operation(partial(function, **kwargs), *model_keys)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 84, in <genexpr>
    model_keys = (make_model_tuple(m) for m in models)
  File "C:\sitios\sistemapagos2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\utils.py", line 22, in make_model_tuple
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Invalid model reference 'api.models.CustomUser'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.
```

I don't know how to work it anymore.

Help to make the auth work with email

Answer (score 0):

Revert the current naming for your AUTH_USER_MODEL in the settings.py file

from:

> AUTH_USER_MODEL = "api.models.CustomUser"

to:

> AUTH_USER_MODEL = "api.CustomUser"

rerun migrations(you may need to run some data migrations or drop the database) and then restart the server.

NB: Anytime you wish to implement a custom User(extending either the AbstractUser or the AbstractBaseUser). It is best to do this at the beginning of the application since alters the database schema greatly.

You can visit this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractuser) for extra information.